# Problemas com maven

Tags: java, oracle, windows, eclipse, maven

Olá eu li como o Maven funciona, porém tem uma coisa que não entendi eu dependerei do maven após criar o meu programa executável ? eu sou iniciante no java,  gostaria de saber também como funciona o uso da biblioteca musicg com maven pois meu objetivo é um executável independente de qualquer coisa instalada porém esse package usa maven, não teria como adiciona-ló normalmente no eclipse ?

Estou tentando executar:
https://lstsal.wordpress.com/2015/02/25/an-easy-way-to-compare-two-audios/

Answer (score 0):

> Eu dependerei do maven após criar o meu programa executável?

Não, não dependerá mais do Maven após gerar seu executável.

O Maven é uma ferramenta voltada para a organização do seu projeto, você vai descrever suas dependências, módulos, componentes externos, plugins, ordem de compilação, tratamentos nos artefatos gerados, seguindo uma série de ações pré definidas (clean, install, package, deploy...)

O processo de geração de um executável, ou um artefato que será utilizado para deploy, ocorre em uma das fases da compilação (package). Existem configurações a se fazer nessa fase, executadas por plugins de empacotamento por exemplo.

---

Em resumo, para gerar o executável de um projeto que utiliza Maven, você deverá realizar o `package` do Maven. Após o artefato gerado, não existe mais necessidade da utilização do Maven, normalmente o resultado da compilação é colocado na pasta `target` (que também pode ser customizada).

---

No seu caso, se o resultado da sua compilação seria um `jar`, bastaria você acessar seu artefato no diretório `target` do projeto, e executar o `jar` normalmente utilizando `java -jar meujar.jar`.

Outro exemplo seria uma compilação de uma aplicação web, o `war` ou `ear` será gerado no diretório `target`, o próximo passo seria disponibilizar este artefato em um servidor web para deploy.

Notou que a interação com o Maven se encerra após a geração dos artefatos?

Comment: Obrigado ajudou muito, amigo estou usando a biblioteca musicg  que foi feita em maven e foi criada para  ser importada no IDE do eclipse  eu posso simplesmente importar um Jar Maven sem o maven instalado ou há necessidade pois não consigo compilar meu programa com o o Package Maven tem alguma ideia do motivo ?

Comment: veja meu projeto tentando importar uma Jarra Maven, a pergunta foi feita para eu entender melhor como o maven funciona já o site explica mais como utilizar em si.

Veja meu outro problema:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/522294/erro-ao-importar-pacote-e-executar-codigo-na-ide-eclipse-java

Comment: Se você está utilizando Maven, você deve utilizar o Maven. Se você adicionar a dependência diretamente na IDE, o Maven não vai ter conhecimento dela

Comment: Caso o seu jar não esteja em um repositório de artefatos, será necessário adicioná-lo lá. [Aqui](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) tem um exemplo de como instalar um artefato de terceiro (um jar sem pom.xml por exemplo), em seu repositório local, para depois adicioná-lo no pom.xml do seu projeto.

Comment: Pode-se dizer que esse comentário que eu fiz é a resposta da pergunta que você adicionou no comentário, não se pode utilizar Maven + dependências na IDE, é preciso incluir via pom.xml apenas, vou copiar a explicação pra la depois.

Comment: obrigado amigo estou no aguardo da explicação lá estou tentando compilar e usei tudo que sei o java mas não é o bastante vou ver mais sobre maven, como você falou acima dependendo só será preciso declarar e configurar o pom.xml